# Class Def not found, Renderer Map in log4j2

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2, noclassdeffounderror, renderer

I have migrated from log4j1 to log4j2 in my project. It worked all fine everywhere in all others plugins but creating a ClassDefNOtFOundError in one plugin.

older log4j jar:  **log4j-1.2.17.jar**
new log4j jar (two jars are used here): **log4j-api-2.13.3.jar**  and **log4j-core-2.13.3.jar**

Throwing below error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/or/RendererMap
        at org.apache.log4j.Hierarchy.<init>(Hierarchy.java:97)
        at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:82)
        at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:104)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.getLogger(Log4JLogger.java:229)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.<init>(Log4JLogger.java:65)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:529)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.or.RendererMap
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        ... 19 more
DEBUG Main - Waiting for thread AIPw-2-Thread-1 to complete...
```

Please help to get rid from this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also added old log4j jar (log4j-1.2.17.jar) in the lib folder, it resolved the issue for now, but its not a good solution. log4j-1.2.17.jar is a vulnerable jar. What is its replacement in log4j2. Need help in that.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got the solution for the problem I was facing.

Solution: by using below jars instead of log4j-api-2.13.3.jar, log4j-core-2.13.3.jar:
**log4j-api-2.14.1.jar,
log4j-core-2.14.1.jar**
only version upgraded from **2.13.3 to 2.14.1**

Detailed analysis below:

First of all, log42 is not only one jar, where each and every dependencies are included. We mostly used below two jars for logging in case of log4j2:

log4j-api-2.13.3.jar
log4j-core-2.13.3.jar

which include most the dependencies but not all.
point to be noted is, these two are not only jars in log4j version 2.13.3, there many more. So the problem was like, RendererMap class is not present in these two jars, but in another package of log42 version 2.13.3
I didn't found the complete package of jar, so didn't got know, in which jar it is.